# Find out from which JAR the current JSF page was loaded from

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jar, classloading

I am calling a bean method from different JSF pages in different JAR files. How can i determine (at runtime) the JAR file from which the JSF page was loaded from?

Is it somehow possible over the FacesContext? I didn't find any solution yet.

Small Example:

> ```
> A.jar
> |-- a.xhtml
> B.jar 
> |-- b.xhtml
> C.jar 
> |-- myBean.class
> ```

MyBean should know if the calling page is coming from A.jar or B.jar

Comment: Why do you need this? What is the usecase?

Comment: We use ResourceBundles for showing the Text on the JSF Pages. 
Our webapp is modular (which is supported since servlet 3.0). Because we want to be able to overwrite specifig texts per module, we customized the loading of the ResourceBundles. 

To decide which text to show on the page, we need to know which module made the request. E.g: If the request is coming from Module A whe show the customized text, otherwise the standard text will be shown.